# NHibernate cascade and inverse

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have three mappings as follows:

```
public MainChapterMap()
{
    // other properties

    HasMany(x => x.ClientSpecific).KeyColumn("MainChapterId");
}

public MainChapterClientMap()
{
    // other properties

    References(x => x.MainChapter).Column("MainChapterId");
    HasMany(x => x.Details).KeyColumn("MainChapterClientId");
}

public MainChapterClientDetailMap()
{
    // other properties

    References(x => x.MainChapterClient).Column("MainChapterClientId");
}
```

`MainChapter` has many client-specific chapters. The client-specific chapters (`MainChapterClient`) has many translations (`MainChapterClientDetail`)

The dele rules should be as follow:

1. When deleting a `MainChapter`

   - Delete the `MainChapterClient` row
   - Delete the `MainChapterClientDetail` row(s)
2. When deleting a `MainChapterClient`

   - Do NOT delete the `MainChapter` row
   - Delete the `MainChapterClientDetail` row(s)
3. When deleting a `MainChapterClientDetail`

   - Do NOT delete the `MainChapter` row
   - Do NOT delete the `MainChapterClientDetail` row(s)

But I no matter what I end up getting this error:

> deleted object would be re-saved by
>   cascade (remove deleted object from
>   associations)[Entities.MainChapterClient#39]

I'm not sure how to set up my cascades anymore. Any help are more than welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the reference from both sides :

```
MainChapterClient.Details.Remove(instance);
instance.MainChapterClient = null;
```